# Json parsing errors while using json_extract_path_text() function in where clause

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have a Redshift table that contains columns with json objects. I am running into json parser failures while trying to execute queries on this table that applies specific filters on the json object content. 
While I am able to use the json_extract_path_text() in the select statements, the same fails when used in where clause.

**Following is the error I see:
Amazon Invalid operation: JSON parsing error;**

When I look at the STL_ERROR table for more details, this is what I see in the error details:
**errcode**: 8001
**context**: JSON parsing error
**error**: invalid json object null

**Following is an example of the content in one such json column:**

```
{"att1":"att1_val","att2":"att2_val","att3":[{"att3_sub1_1":"att3_sub1_1_val","att3_sub1_2":"att3_sub1_2_val"},{"att3_sub2_1":"att3_sub2_1_val","att3_sub2_2":"att3_sub2_2_val"}],"att4":"att4_val","att5":"att5_val"}
```

Now when I run the following query, it executes without any issues:

```
select
json_extract_path_text(col_with_json_obj,'att4') as required_val
from table_with_json_data;
```

Now when I use the json_extract_path_text() in the where clause it fails with the above error:

```
select
json_extract_path_text(col_with_json_obj,'att4') as required_val
from table_with_json_data
where json_extract_path_text(col_with_json_obj,'att4') = 'att4_val';
```

Is there anything that I am using incorrectly or missing here?

P.S: I have another table with similar schema and the same queries run just fine on that. The only difference between the two tables is the way the data is loaded - one uses **jsonpaths file** in the copy options and the other uses **json 'auto'**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the error you would receive if `table_with_json_data` contained even a single row in which the value of `col_with_json_obj` was the four-character string "null".

To avoid errors like this in general I'd recommend creating a Redshift UDF for validating JSON. The is_json() method described at http://discourse.snowplowanalytics.com/t/more-robust-json-parsing-in-redshift-with-python-udfs/197 has worked well for me:

```
create or replace function is_json(j varchar(max))
  returns boolean
  stable as $$
    import json
    try:
      json_object = json.loads(j)
    except ValueError, e:
      return False
    return True
  $$ language plpythonu;
```

Then you could add a `and where is_json(col_with_json_obj)` clause to your query and this class of errors can be avoided entirely.

Comment: Thanks Jason.. Yeah, I noticed that few of the rows had the string value "null" and had to explicitly filter them out.. However the thing that I still don't understand is why it works in "select" statement and not in where clause. To be precise, the conditions that I have in my where clause should filter out rows that had the string "null" for this column.

Comment: @Hercules I've had the same confusion and frustration. There's a question on the AWS Redshift forum you can follow, but there is no response yet: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=232468